# Understanding the RAM address of a 7 segment 4 digit display (HT1668)

Tags: spi, led-driver, 7segmentdisplay

I've salvaged a 7 segment display and I comes with an ht1668 driver IC with half duplex SPI for communication. I was reading the datasheet and understood the communication side, but couldn't understand how and where data should be written to the driver, the [datasheet](http://www.artschip.com/pdf/HT1668.PDF) doesn't provide further explanations, and I'm stuck here.

I tried interfacing it with an already available Arduino library, but I found that there are some connections wired different in the PCB and the library doesn't allow for pin configurations. So no luck. So my only option is to communicate manually using the SPI and datasheet.
Can you suggest me some resources where they have explained this?

Comment: what explanation do you need? You say the datasheet defines what things you can send via SPI, so send these?